# Convert a .X mesh to a modern format

Tags: mesh, gltf, conversion

I have a bunch of meshes in the .X format, which isn't supported by many 3D applications today. Therefore, I would like to convert these to a modern format like fbx or gltf/glb.

Since these meshes are proprietary, an offline solution would be preferred. What would be an ideal way to achieve this lossless-ly?

Comment: Do you have the spec for the format?

Comment: @ratchetfreak this is the closest I know to a spec: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/directx/ | Also, msdn documentation on the same: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173014(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Blender appears to have a .X importer.  It's a plugin that ships with Blender, but is disabled by default, so you have to enable it in User Preferences.  See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8749/18161

Blender also has a glTF exporter.  For now that's a separate download, from here: [glTF-Blender-Exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter)

Comment: I tried this method out. One of the problems I faced was that the textures went missing. Furthermore, the dimensions all got messed up. Is there something I am missing? (I just imported a .X, deleted the default light source/camera and exported to .glb)

Comment: The glTF exporter does have some tricky rules for materials given that it is trying to do PBR.  It ships with documentation on that.  The dimensions should be simple to get right though.  If you can produce a non-proprietary blend file that shows the dimensions problem, maybe you could post an issue on that.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. Keeping the question open right now to see if any other method comes up. :)

Comment: Update: Blender doesn't seem to import .X files anymore :/ Only export is supported.

Comment: That's lousy.  It still has import in the name, but I don't see it in my import menu either.  I wonder when that changed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) will work for you? In particular, it has a [command line tool for converting between formats](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/tree/master/tools/assimp_cmd).